# $\frac{dy}{d \theta} = {e^y\sin^2(\theta)\over {y\sec(\theta)}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integration

Please help me solve the above differential equation. I'm confused as to the steps required to obtain the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: The equation is separable, so rewrite and integrate both sides as:

$$\displaystyle \int e^{-y}~ y ~dy = \int \cos \theta~ \sin^2 \theta ~d \theta$$

Comment: Another hint - the left hand side requires integration by parts, the right hand side by substitution.

Comment: @Xenyal: You are very welcome. Regards